# R Shiny DashboardPage search input

Tags: r, shiny

I have a UI that is projectdashboard in R shiny. I want to be able to type in a text/search box and have the data associated with it show up as i type.

```
server <- function(input, output,session) {
   output$ui_names = renderUI({
name_list = mydata()[,"names"]
pickerInput("name", label=h3(" Names:"),
            choices = sort(unique(name_list)),options = list("actions-box" = TRUE,"live-search" = TRUE,"none-selected-text"='Select Names'),
            selected = NULL,multiple = TRUE)
})
ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(title=textOutput("title"),titleWidth = 1500),
dashboardSidebar(
       uiOutput("ui_names")
)
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This however does not give me expected or working results. How can i put a text/searchbar in the dashboard side bar, that will 'live-search' the data i am feeding it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following:

```
sidebarSearchForm(textId = "searchText", buttonId = "searchButton",label = "Search...")
```

Please check if this meet your requirements

Comment: will this perform a live data search on my data. (mydata())?

Comment: You need to code it accordingly.I am not sure about this but a try can always worthy.